# Customize CKEditor Format plugin to a simple button

Tags: ckeditor

Built-in Format plugin is dropdown list of possible tags (h1,h2,p,pre..). List of tags can be easily configured in config file.

I use only one tag so having dropdown just complicates toolbar and affects usability.

Would it be possible to customize the existing plugin or create new one that would:

1) be simple button instead of dropdown, with custom icon

2) when button is clicked is would add predefined format H1 to selected text

Simply said, toolbar button that would simulate the dropdown item selection click on 'Heading 1'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874133/customize-ckeditor-format-plugin-to-a-simple-button-updates please review this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as i recall format doesn't provide convenient interface for external calls, but you can create your own plugin.

Essentially it comes down to use **CKEDITOR.style** object:

```
// Creates a style object, 
var styleObj = new CKEDITOR.style( { element: 'pre' } );

editor.applyStyle( styleObj );
// Or if you wish to remove style:
// editor.removeStyle( styleObj );
```

I've created simple, full featured sample plugin, called **myFormat**:

```
( function() {

    "use strict";

    var pluginName = 'myFormat';

    CKEDITOR.plugins.add( pluginName, {
        icons: pluginName, // If you wish to have an icon...

        init: function( editor ) {
            // Tagname which you'd like to apply.
            var tag = 'h2',
                // Note: that we're reusing.
                //style = new CKEDITOR.style( editor.config[ 'format_' + tag ] );
                style = new CKEDITOR.style( { element: 'pre' } );

            // Creates a command for our plugin, here command will apply style. All the logic is
            // inside CKEDITOR.styleCommand#exec function so we don't need to implement anything.
            editor.addCommand( pluginName, new CKEDITOR.styleCommand( style ) );

            // This part will provide toolbar button highlighting in editor.
            editor.attachStyleStateChange( style, function( state ) {
                !editor.readOnly && editor.getCommand( pluginName ).setState( state );
            } );

            // This will add button to the toolbar.
            editor.ui.addButton( 'MyFormat', {
                label: 'Click to apply format',
                command: pluginName,
                toolbar: 'insert,5'
            } );
        }
    } );

} )();
```

Just put the code to `<ckeditorDirectory>/ckeditor-dev/plugins/myFormat/plugin.js`.

Don't forget to modify your CKEditor config to include **myFormat** plugin, and place some fancy icon to `<ckeditorDirectory>/ckeditor-dev/plugins/myFormat/icons/myFormat.png`.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, it works great. One question though: If you click twice on the format button, the applied format will be removed, but the original <p> will be replaced with <div>. How can I avoid that?